# JENKINS installation pasword and user forgotten

Tags: windows, jenkins, passwords

I installed jenkins on windows and forgot the username and the password I'm unable to locate the config.xml file nor do I have access to jenkins how to reset password and username. I also tried reinstalling not helping.

Logging in to the jenkins through browser localhost 8080 port.